# How can I read different log4j.properties file depending on an argument in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, log4j

With the same code, I want to run it both as a real mode and a dev mode.

So I added a `service-mode` argument, and it decides the port, database name, etc.

I also want to make a log file for a dev mode.

But using log4j, it seems that configuration about logging is decided when app is started.

Is there a way to change the log file path depending on a given argument?

I expected something like:

```
// Main.java
if (args.serviceMode is real) {
  setLogging(log4j.properties)
}
else {
  setLogging(log4j.properties.dev)
}
```

or

```
// log4j.properties
log4j.appender.file.File=/path/to/real/log
log4jdev.appender.file.File=/path/to/dev/log
```

```
// Main.java
if (args.serviceMode is real) {
  setLogPath(log4j.appender.file.File)
}
else {
  setLogPath(log4jdev.appender.file.File)
}
```

Any link or comment appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `spring.profiles` in your `application.yml` and set new log-name

```
spring.profiles: dev
logging.file: new-app.log
```

More information you can find get [here](https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-yaml/)